# Why I am getting "Fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, linked-list

I am using `Node` class to create a `node` of `linked list`. It is simple implementation and incomplete. I used pointer `first` as static I thought it would be better choice as I am going to use it once. And that is when I am going to store address of first `Node`. but when I try to compile I am getting following error.

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   class Node * Node::first" (?first@Node@@2PAV1@A)
>   1>c:\users\labeeb\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\linked
>   list1\Debug\linked list1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
>   externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Note: I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{

public:
    static Node *first;

    Node *next;
    int data;

    Node()
    {
        Node *tmp = new Node; // tmp is address of newly created node.
        tmp->next = NULL;
        tmp->data = 0; //intialize with 0

        Node::first = tmp; 



    }


    void insert(int i)
    {

        Node *prev=NULL , *tmp=NULL;

        tmp = Node::first;

        while( tmp->next != NULL)  // gets address of Node with link = NULL
        {
            //prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;

        }

        // now tmp has address of last node. 

        Node *newNode = new Node; // creates new node.
        newNode->next = NULL;     // set link of new to NULL  
        tmp->next = newNode;  // links last node to newly created node. 

        newNode->data = i;  // stores data in newNode

    }



};

int main()
{

    Node Node::*first = NULL;
    Node n;




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this line from inside `main` to file scope, and change it slightly:

```
Node* Node::first = NULL;
```

As written, you are declaring a local variable named `first`, of type "pointer to member of class `Node`, with type `Node`". This local variable is distinct from and unrelated to `Node::first`.